# Power set axiom

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I want to write it in the following language  $L=\{\in,=\}\cup \{u_{0},u_{1},\ldots\}$. Here is an attempt $\forall x~\exists y~\forall z~\in x~[z=p\wedge p\subset y]$.
I also want to show whether it fails at $(V_{\omega},\in)$ and $(V_{\omega+1},\in)$. $(V_{\omega},\in)$ models it because $\omega$ is a limit ordinal. Any hint for the $(V_{\omega+1},\in)$?
thanks

Comment: What is $p{}{}$?

Comment: What is $V_{\omega}$, etc. ?

Comment: @hardmath The sets $V_\alpha$ form the cumulative hierarchy whose union is the universe of (pure) sets. They can be defined recursively by setting, for each ordinal $\alpha$, $V_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}\mathcal P(V_\beta)$, where $\mathcal P$ is the power set operator. (This is standard notation in set theory and logic.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I don't know what $p$ is, but $Z=p\wedge p\subseteq y$ implies $z\subseteq y$, and $\forall x\exists y\forall z\in x[z\subseteq y]$ looks a lot like the axiom of union to me, rather than the power set axiom.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: I think Tomas might want to include more details in the Question, esp. the constructive hierarchy (if that's the point).  The title and first sentence suggest the problem is about formulating a "power set axiom", so possibly there's a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem if we're trying to define a power set axiom while using it to build $V_{\omega},V_{\omega+1},$ etc.

Comment: @hardmath There is nothing about a "constructive" hierarchy here, and the notation is standard, there is no need to clutter the question. It is a problem about formalizing mathematical statements in first order logic, and satisfiability in first order structures. (No chicken-and-egg stuff either.)

Answer (score 4):

Um, your attempt contains $\subset$ which isn't in the language you want to stick to ... so it fails already there. (It also fails because it contains a free variable $p$ that comes out of nowhere, and even if those two are fixed it seems to become something like the union axiom, not the power set axiom).

The usual power set axiom (which you ought to be able to find in any text on axiomatic set theory, so I don't think I'm giving anything away here) is

$$ \forall x \exists y \forall z ( z\in y \iff z\subseteq x ) $$
where $\subseteq$ is an abbreviation, so the actual axiom is
$$ \forall x \exists y \forall z ( z\in y \iff \forall w(w\in z \implies w\in x )) $$

---

**Hint** for the second part: $V_{\omega+1}$ contains $V_{\omega}$ as an element ...

Comment: thanks. Can you elaborate a bit on your hint? $P(V_{\omega})$ exists so it doesn't contradict the axiom. Also, can you give a hint for the power axiom formulation?

Comment: @TKM: What do you mean by "a hint for the power axiom formulation"?

Comment: @TKM: Yes, $\mathcal P(V_{\omega})$ exists _in our world_, but it is not a member of $V_{\omega+1}$. There is not even a powerset of $V_{\omega}$ _relative to_ $V_{\omega+1}$, because such a relative power set certainly needs to contain $V_\omega$ itself as member, but then its rank is too large to be a member of $V_{\omega+1}$.

Comment: thanks. I mean a hint on how to reformulate it in $L=\{\in,=\}\cup \{u_{0},u_{1},\ldots\}$.

Comment: Though,I don't see any symbol in $\forall x \exists y \forall z(z\in y \leftrightarrow \forall w(w\in z\rightarrow w\in x))$ that is not also in L.